# what's the next of RKManagedObject in RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, magicalrecord

I just read the [tutorial](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/382c3cf3743fec241eb95d3f569f3cd2017f1120/Docs/MobileTuts%20Advanced%20RestKit/Advanced_RestKit_Tutorial.md#working-with-core-data) on github, and found some object methods about Core Data, for example, `fetchRequest`, `objectWithPrimaryKeyValue` and so on. Then I googled them, all of them come from `RKManagedObject`, which has been deprecated in the latest version of Restkit, so do current version of Restkit provide similar API of NSManagedObject?

Or should I just involve third-party project, such as `MagicalRecord`? If so, I'm not sure whether they are compatible, since core data is handled by RestKit heavily. For example, If I want to use `MagicalRecord`, I need to init it with one of below method according to official doc. And my application will have two main contexts I guess, one is handled by `RestKit`, another is handled by `MagicalRecord`.

```
+ (void)setupCoreDataStack;
+ (void)setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack;
+ (void)setupCoreDataStackWithInMemoryStore;
+ (void)setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:(NSString *)storeName;
+ (void)setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:(NSString *)storeName;
+ (void)setupCoreDataStackWithStoreAtURL:(NSURL *)storeURL;
+ (void)setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreAtURL:(NSURL *)storeURL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restkit is for mapping, not to provide a different interface to core data. As such you get a few things, like saving support, in [NSManagedObjectContext+RKAdditions.h](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/development/Code/CoreData/NSManagedObjectContext%2BRKAdditions.h) but nothing else.

You should look at using [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator) for sure and consider magical record if there are other things you want that it provides.

Comment: Thanks @Wain, I just updated my question with my concern about involving the third-party project, not sure whether this's a good way to ask question, since it's a across domain question, so please feel free to raise your concern.

Comment: You can use them together, there are various guides, something like https://gist.github.com/chourobin/4727113